# Replacing @string/stringId in Android dynamically

Tags: android, xml

I want to dynamically fetch the string translations in the android layout xml files, so basically wherever @string/stringId is used in the XML files, a java function should be invoked for this string Id to fetch the corresponding translation.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not directly. Android R offers a `ResourceLoader` that will help with this sort of thing, and I hope that `AppCompatActivity` will offer a backport of that sometime in the future.

Comment: Do you mean fetching the translations from a remote resource?

Comment: @CommonWare, can you elaborate more? How can I use the ResourceLoader so that It calls my function wherever @string/ is used in the layout xml? I can modify the annotation to pass the string Ids to my function but how to invoke the Resource Loader using xml?

Comment: @Cory Roy, Yes. Only String Ids will be stored in the App, Based on the user locale in shared preferences or from input, translations will be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's possible, but it sounds quite unnecessary.

Have you read over:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization

Generally, you have a separate XML file for each language using the same string keys but located in directories named by their locale.

> Example:
>
> Suppose that your app's default language is English. Suppose also that
>   you want to localize all the text in your app to French, and most of
>   the text in your app (everything except the app's title) to Japanese.
>   In this case, you could create three alternative `strings.xml` files,
>   each stored in a locale-specific resource directory:
>
> `res/values/strings.xml` Contains English text for all the strings that
>   the app uses, including text for a string named title.
>   `res/values-fr/strings.xml` Contain French text for all the strings,
>   including title. `res/values-ja/strings.xml` Contain Japanese text for
>   all the strings except title. If your Java-based code refers to
>   `R.string.title`, here is what happens at runtime:
>
> If the device is set to any language other than French, Android loads
>   title from the `res/values/strings.xml` file. If the device is set to
>   French, Android loads title from the `res/values-fr/strings.xml` file.

Then you can choose to hard-code the stringId (via `@string/title`) in your xml layout file or assign the strings programmatically in java via (`view.setText(R.string.title)`)

Comment: Hi these strings are statically stored in the XML files and my requirement is to fetch the strings dynamically at run time that is why want to replace the @string annotation to something that will invoke my Map populated at runtime

Comment: @Sahil I did an implementation where we would cache server localizations locally.  If these strings aren't changing too quickly you might be able to prefetch them, store them in room or shared prefs to grab at the time to bind the view?

Comment: Binding the view in code and setting the string is a lot of effort. I am going with the approach of creating custom views in which my map will be invoked to fetch the translation. So, @string/string_id gets replaced by string_id in the custom view and I will replace with translation in the overridden setText method.

Answer (score 0):

**In XML File**

```
android:text="@string/app_name"
```

Replace app_name to your string

**In Java File**

```
TextView t;
t.setText.(getString(R.string.YOUR_STRING_NAME));
```

Comment: Hi, I cannot replace directly in the XML file as I only have the stringIds during compile time. I will populate my Map during Runtime by invoking my API and then I can use this map to get the translation.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for this post, but in case anyone needs it, there's a library that does that (If you don't mind having external dependencies) called "restring". Here is a [Medium](https://medium.com/@hamidgh/dynamically-change-bundled-strings-a24b97bfd306) post that explains it, and its [Github](https://github.com/B3nedikt/restring) repo.